# Подсеть - это namespace?

Tags: сеть, сетевое-программирование

Можно ли, говоря в терминах программирования, сказать, что подсеть сети - это namespace в языках программирования?

Comment: смотря по каким критериям сравнивать, и что вы вынесите в абстракцию из этих двух "штук"

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц если мы рассматриваем их, как способ группировки с целью сокрытия не нужных вещей для остальных. Надеюсь, смог ясно выразиться.